# How to hide a WebMarkUpContainer checking an AjaxCheckBox in Wicket

Tags: java, ajax, wicket

OK basically I have a WebMarkUpContainer which contains a DateTextField component and I want to make it visible only when I check an AjaxCheckBox.

In general my code is:

```
private static final class Results extends BootstrapForm<ResultsModel>
    {

 final AjaxCheckBox isExamsSuccess = new AjaxCheckBox("isExamsSuccess") {           

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                updateModel();
                toggleStep(target);                 
            }
        };          

        final WebMarkupContainer wmc = new WebMarkupContainer("wmc");

        final DateTextField startDate = new DateTextField("startDate",
                    new DateTextFieldConfig()
                       .autoClose(true).withFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")
                       .withLanguage("el").withEndDate(new DateTime()));


public Results(String id, CompoundPropertyModel<ResultsModel> propertyModel)
        {

            super(id, propertyModel);           
            add(isExamsSuccess);
            wmc.add(startDate);
            add(wmc);

  protected void toggleStep(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            if(isExamsSuccess.getModelObject() == true){
                isExamsSuccess.setModelObject(true);
                wmc.setVisible(true);
                target.add(wmc);
            }                        
            else {               
                wmc.setVisible(false);                
                target.add(wmc);
            }            
        }
}
```

I would really appreciate some help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks good! You just need to set the initial visibility of `wmc` to depend on `isExamsSuccess`:

```
wmc = new WebMarkupContainer("wmc") {
   @Override public void onConfigure() {
     super.onConfigure();
     setVisible(isExamsSuccess.getModelObject());
   }
}
wmc.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
```

In addition you need to call `setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true)` because Wicket needs to be able to find the HTML element to turn the visibility from `off` to `on`.